# How to correctly setup redirection with Python Requests for some corner-cases

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import requests
from requests import exceptions

try:
    url=sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print('No URL provided.')
    sys.exit(1)

print('\n--- {}\n'.format(url))

try:
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(url)
except exceptions.TooManyRedirects as t:
    print('ERROR: {}'.format(t))
    r = s.get(url, allow_redirects=False)

print('-----------------------------')
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers)
```

The code takes a URL as input and tries to run a GET request on it. 
I use the session object to manage Cookies over multiple requests etc.

Now my problem is, that I have a couple of URLs (mostly Tumblr), that will run in a infinite redirection loop and break after 30 attempts.

Example: http://ansgar-skoda.tumblr.com/post/96703389502

When I request this page with a browser or with

```
curl -v -L http://ansgar-skoda.tumblr.com/post/96703389502
```

the redirection works and I'll receive the correct webpage.
It seems I am not setting up this correctly. When studying the Requests docu, I saw that the option allow_redirects is True by default. The user-agent doesn't seem to affect the result in this case.

Any hints how to proceed here? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strangely this works in Python 2, but I see the same problem as you for Python 3 - same requests package (2.13.0) on both.

Comment: Awesome. Very well spotted. I'll pass this on to the issue tracker of Requests.

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, this is a bug in Requests
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3949